# Google Analytics Goal funnel setup not reporting correct numbers

Tags: google-analytics

We have setup a completion goal in Google Analytics, that should match steps based on the beginning of the URL.
The setup screenshot:
[image]

But in the funnel visualization the "Car detail" page is not counted properly, as some of the car details hits are actually counted in the "exit" part of the "Car list" page:
[image]

The URL matching is set to "Begins with", so it should match the "Car details" urls, that end with /..../car/$CAR_ID/. However it seems that those are not counted in "Car details" step. Is there any other way to make Google Analytics report correct numbers for "dynamic" URLs?

Comment: You could try to use regex matching to be more precise with what gets passed through each step, thus giving you a bit more control.

Comment: We actually though of using that, but it seemed more error prone and "Begins with" should actually be more straightforward. If we don't have any other choice, we'll try regex. However I have a feeling that it will not be any different, since we'll be doing the same "Begins with" but in regex format.

Comment: The difference I see would be how you are capture (or not) the dynamic parameters in `/used/.../car/1234/`. The Begins with will capture everything that begins with `/used/.../car/`, even if it's not what you want, but you could limit that with a regex to include only things that look like `/used/..../car/XXXXX/`.

Comment: How many hits do you see on the /success page?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a situation I recently came across.

My logic was very similar to yours:

The goal URLs contained a `?` (query string) but everything before the query string was the same so I thought "starts with" would be the logical choice (and less error prone).

It turns out that [URLs containing special characters require the RegEx matching](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. We have tried RegEx, but without much success. We are in contact with the GA team now. I'll post here if we get a good answer.

Comment: How did you go with this @Matic?

Comment: Google helped us with the regex and now it kind of works: `\/used\/.*\/car\/$`